# Python pg8000 SQL, INSERT INTO... doesn`t write Information into table

Tags: python, sql

I am connecting to a SQL-Database (heroku) and I am able to create a table there.

When inserting some information I don`t get any error.
But when I want to  read the data it returns "None".
What am I doing wrong?

```
import pg8000

conn = pg8000.connect(user="username", password="password", 
host="hostAddress", port=5432, database="database", 
ssl=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()

def createTable():
    cursor.execute("create table test (ID INT, TITLE TEXT)")
    conn.commit()

def dataEntry():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 'blablabla')")
    conn.commit()

def readTable():
    print (cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test "))

#createTable()
dataEntry()
readTable()
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Any reason why you're using pg8000 over the more prevalent psycopg2? Just curious

Comment: basically it was the first module that worked for me in that constallation.. without any additional elements on my own machine..

Comment: But will look into it.. as a didn`t know it`s way more common.. probably better results for troubleshooting there..

Answer (score 1):

basically the mistake was the projection of the result..

the table was created correctly, 
but instead:

```
print (cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test "))
```

doing:

```
result = (cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test "))
print (results)
```

that does the job..